# How to Query Android DownloadManager with sorting?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, android-download-manager

I am trying to create a custom download activity/page, and I plan to build it on top of the Android DownloadManager. But seems DownloadManager has no public sorting options, all the sorting stuff is hidden, is there a way around this? I'd like to sort by date, or file size.

Thanks,

Johnny

Comment: Interesting question, but I think you need to provide more details. By "it" I assume you mean the DownloadManager. What do you want to sort?

Comment: Correct, sorting by Date or File size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/app/DownloadManager.java#DownloadManager.Query) you can find that DownloadManger. Query can only be sorted by lastModifyDate. So I use the way to extract using source code of DownloadManger and rewrite its sorted method.

Using like this:

```
AppDownloadManager.Query query = new AppDownloadManager.Query();
query.setFilterByStatus(AppDownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING | AppDownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED | AppDownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING | AppDownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED);
query.orderBy(AppDownloadManager.COLUMN_ID, AppDownloadManager.Query.ORDER_DESCENDING);
```

It's first time I answer question in StackOverFlow and  I think my English is poor .tks

Comment: query.orderBy is hidden, private api.

Comment: so I recommend you extract source code and change it.Make your own downloadmanager.I did  and it worked.

Comment: that might break in the future